# How to load a text file into R where a column contains data points separated by comma

Tags: r

I have a text file with two variables(data points) - the first variable is for student ID and the second variable contains a set of grades for each student ID.

The format is student_id,{grades}

For example:

```
0,80,1001,65,71,402,99,50,03,904
```

indicates

```
  student_id=0 has grades{80,100} 
  student_id=2 has grades{65,71,40} and so on.
```

I'd like to get a data frame in R as follows

```
student_id   grades   
0            80,100 
1            65,71,40 
2            99,50,0 
3            90 
4
```

I tried the following command to load the data into R

```
x <- read.delim(file, header=TRUE, row.names=NULL)
```

and this is what I ended up with

```
    student_id. .grades.
1              0,80,100 
2              1,65,71,40 
3              2,99,50,0 
4              3,90 
5              4
```

I'd appreciate any help as to how to go about this problem. Please let me know if you would like me to provide more information. Thanks!

Comment: The problem is not well defined. Each student has how many grades?

Comment: How are you supposed to distinguish grades from student IDs if they're both just separated by commas, and each student doesn't necessarily have the same number of grades? I'm not even talking in terms of R code, just try to explain how someone looking at your example data could know which is which.

Comment: I'd use `readLines` and then `strsplit` on commas.  stuff everything after the first into a list.  The issue is that you cannot have a data.frame with varying number of columns per row...

Comment: @Marius: there's one student ID in each row, and it's whitespace-separated (not that this isn't an ugly format).  If it were all comma-separated you could (with a little bit of care) use `read.csv(...,fill=TRUE)`

Comment: Surely I miss something here, but what does this line do in your example: `0,80,1001,65,71,402,99,50,03,904`?

Comment: Ugh. I totally misread the question and thought it was as @agstudy also supposed ... not the mind-reading exercise that the OP offers.  Looks like we are supposed to be able to figure out that '1001' is broken into '100/1' and '904' is broken into '90/4', etc.  Human-parseable, but just barely. OP: as written your original line makes a **really hard** parsing problem ... Can we assume that student numbers are sequential???   Can we assume that all grades are formatted as two digits unless they're 0?  (i.e. no grades between 1 and 9??) This almost requires a finite-state machine to parse ...

Comment: OP: are there at least line breaks?

Comment: PS if `read.delim` worked for the OP, then there really are line breaks and tab separators in the original file, and it's the initial example that's messed up.

Comment: @BenBolker totally agree with your last comment. That's why I didn't delete my answer yet:)

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand exactly what is the your problem input. But here I assume that you have something like this :

```
x <- readLines(textConnection(
"student_id   grades   
0            80,100 
1            65,71,40 
2            99,50,0 
3            90 
4"))
```

Then using `read.table` like this after replacing all spaces by `|` and use it as a regular separator:

```
   res <- read.table(text=gsub('\\s+','|',x),sep='|',header=TRUE,fill=TRUE)
```

you get this table:

```
  student_id   grades  X
1          0   80,100 NA
2          1 65,71,40 NA
3          2  99,50,0 NA
4          3       90 NA
5          4          NA
```

Of course it is easy to remove the last column like this :

```
res[,-ncol(res)]
  student_id   grades
1          0   80,100
2          1 65,71,40
3          2  99,50,0
4          3       90
5          4
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit tricky because it's a mixture of whitespace- and comma-delimited. My solution is a bit ugly -- maybe someone will come up with something better.

```
x <- readLines(textConnection(
"student_id   grades   
0            80,100 
1            65,71,40 
2            99,50,0 
3            90 
4"))

padNA <- function(x,maxLen) {
    if ((L <- (maxLen-length(x)))>0) x <- c(x,rep(NA,L))
    x
}
getPos <- function(x,n) if (length(x)>=n) x[[n]] else ""
## separate student IDs
student_id <- sapply(strsplit(x[-1],"\\s+"),getPos,1)
## (convert to numeric if you want)
## separate scores
scores <- sapply(strsplit(x[-1],"\\s+"),getPos,2)
## split scores by comma and pad to max length
scoreMat <- do.call(rbind,lapply(strsplit(scores,","),padNA,5))
## convert from character to numeric
storage.mode(scoreMat) <- "numeric"
## combine
data.frame(student_id,scoreMat)
```